# Get value from HashMap

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I want to get values from HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> usageData = new HashMap<>();

        HashMap<String, Integer> usageData2 = new HashMap<>();
        usageData2.put("cpu0", (int) (Math.random() * 100));

        usageData.put("temp", usageData2);

        HashMap<String, Integer> usageData3 = new HashMap<>();
        usageData3.put("cpu1", (int) (Math.random() * 100));

        usageData.put("temp", usageData3);

        HashMap<String, Integer> usageData4 = new HashMap<>();
        usageData4.put("cpu2", (int) (Math.random() * 100));

        usageData.put("temp", usageData4);
```

Then I get the data using this method:

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> getHahMap(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> diagnosticMap)
                {
                    HashMap<String, Integer> value = diagnosticMap.get("temp");
                    return value;
                }
```

At the end I get only the values cpu2 and the random number.
In my case it's very important to keep this structure. How I can solve this issue?

When I receive the data I don't know the String key but I should get the inner HashMap. Is there any abstract way to get HashMapKeys no matter of the values?

EDIT:

I can very quickly solve the problem if there is a way to cut the keys and get only the values of the main HashMap.

Comment: You can only have one value for any given key in a `HashMap`.  Every time you call `usageData.put("temp", whicheverMap)`, you overwrite whatever was in `usageData` before.  It kind of looks like you ought to have only one `HashMap<String, Integer>`, not three?

Comment: Considering you've been posting Java questions for well over a year, I think it's a bit disingenuous to start this question with "I'm new to Java."

Comment: Sorry my fiend but I can't know everything about Java.

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the same value multiple times:

```
    usageData.put("temp", usageData2);

    usageData.put("temp", usageData3); //replaces usageData2

    usageData.put("temp", usageData4); //replaces usageData3
```

Comment: Is there a way to cut the keys and get only the values of the main HashMap?

Comment: @PeterPenzov You're thinking of a `Set` I believe.

Comment: Yes, but then (for what you're doing) there's no point using a `HashMap`.  You should just use a `Set` and iterate over it.

Comment: You can use this diagnosticMap.keySet();

Comment: @AmanChhabra actually, I think he would want to use diagnosticMap.values() -- he said he doesn't want the keys

Comment: Ok, last question, how I can get only the inner HashMap?

Comment: `usageData.values()` will give you a collection of the values (without the keys), but because you're replacing the previous values, you'll only get usageData4 back.  Really, there's no reason for you to be using HashMaps at all.

Comment: Yeah right Eric
@Peter: Then you can use ArrayList<HashMap<String,Integer>> I think that will be a better option because in any case you are not using keys anywhere

Comment: @PeterPenzov: What do you mean, "only the inner HashMap"?  Either you have an outer map and you need a key to look up _one_ of the inner maps, or you have only one map and there is no outer or inner map.  Nothing else makes any real sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can retrieve the keys using

```
diagnosticMap.keySet();
```

If you want to retrieve only values, you can get it using

```
diagnosticMap.values();
```

But if you are not going to use key anyways, I think you should use

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Integer>>
```

Instead of

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Integer>>
```

If you want to use ArrayList here is how you can deal with data

```
List<HashMap<String, Integer>> usageData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();

        HashMap<String, Integer> usageData2 = new HashMap<>();
        usageData2.put("cpu0", (int) (Math.random() * 100));

        usageData.add(usageData2);

        HashMap<String, Integer> usageData3 = new HashMap<>();
        usageData3.put("cpu1", (int) (Math.random() * 100));

        usageData.add(usageData3);

        HashMap<String, Integer> usageData4 = new HashMap<>();
        usageData4.put("cpu2", (int) (Math.random() * 100));

        usageData.add(usageData4);
```

And to retrieve the values:

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> getHahMap(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> diagnosticMap,int index)
                {
                    HashMap<String, Integer> value = diagnosticMap.get(index);
                    return value;
                }
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: I tried to do HashMap<String, Integer> values = (HashMap<String, Integer>) diagnosticMap.values(); but I get NPE. After  I get ArrayList<HashMap<String,Integer>> how I can convert it to HashMap<String,Integer>?

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate your usage of the "middle-man" map, and just store those keys directly:

```
Map<String, Integer> info = new HashMap<>();
info.put("cpu1", /* your int */);
Integer value = info.get("cpu1");
```